# How to record audio of a stream radio at scheduled times with FFmpeg in CentOS?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, audio-streaming

I would like to do a similar service to censury.com.br, something that records my radio at certain times, in .mp3 files with different names according to the recording. EX: stream08-19-2019-22-00.mp3

I'm very new but ffmpeg sounds like the perfect way to record my favorite radio shows.

I like some specific times of three radios and a VPS with CentOS, to be able to record these programs would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

## One time recording

You can use the `at` command do schedule a command or script:

```
at 14:30:00
```

A prompt will appear where you can enter your scheduled command:

```
at > ffmpeg -i input -t 01:00:00 -c copy "$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S).m4a"
```

The example above will record for one hour (`-t 01:00:00`).

To save press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.

To view the scheduled job use the `atq` command.

## Repetitive recording

You can use `crontab` to create cron jobs that will be executed on a periodic, fixed schedule:

```
crontab -e
```

Then enter your command:

```
0 16 * * 3 ffmpeg -i input -t 01:00:00 -c copy "$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S).m4a"
```

The above example will record every Wednesday at 16:00 for one hour (`-t 01:00:00`).

You can view your cron jobs with `crontab -l`.

Comment: Hi, llogan. Thanks for you fast reply. I believe that for my need the best option is crontab.

Let's say I want to record this radio every Wednesday at 4:00 pm for an hour, would that be exactly the code?

0 2 * * wed ffmpeg -i https://c2901-slbps-sambavideos.akamaized.net/radio/FMoDiaAudio_14d480346fa04ebcb4f03173f2dae707/livestream/chunklist.m3u8 -t 01:00:00 -c copy radio.aac

Comment: In the case of another radio record every Saturday from 20:00 to 22:00.

0 20 * * sat ffmpeg -i http://167.114.103.39:8766/stream -t 02:00:00 -c copy anotherrecord.aac

Comment: In either case, how would I make the recording file names have names according to the day?

Comment: @Rodrigo Answer updated to address follow-up questions.

Comment: so cron starts counting days on sunday at index 0